# CoreML how to Normalize input array

Tags: ios, scikit-learn, coreml, coremltools

I try to convert sklearn normalizer to coreml model like the following:

```
normalized = sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer()

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(normalized)
```

But I get this error:

"Error processing feature list: If a single feature name is given, then num_dimensions must be provided"

How I can set "**num_dimensions**"?

Another option is directly using the Normalizer in CoreML:

https://apple.github.io/coremltools/coremlspecification/sections/FeatureEngineering.html#normalizer

But there is zero documentation how can I utilize this functionality in IOS. How can I run this on a float array for instance?

Answer (score 2):

To create a normalizer inside Core ML, you need to build a pipeline model. A pipeline is simply a sequence of Core ML models, bundled up as a new Core ML model.

The first model in the pipeline would be the `Normalizer` model. The second would be your regular model. The output from the normalizer model then becomes the input of your regular model.

You can do this by hand (see my book, link in my profile) but really, it's easiest to let the scikit-learn converter handle this because that's what it is for.

The `num_dimensions` error happens because just converting an sklearn `Normalizer` does not give the coremltools converter enough information to work with. If you want to do normalization in scikit-learn, it looks like you also need to create a pipeline model in scikit-learn and convert that.

Comment: Thanks I already have book! Nice one. Pipelines seems nice But still does not answer my problem of how to convert a normalized input with corelmltools. Its not clear for me what you mean "it looks like you also need to create a pipeline model in scikit-learn and convert that" ? On the other hand since scikit normalization is supported by coremltools, I dont think I am the only one who encountered this problem. Isnt there any offical example/solution to this?

Comment: sklearn's Normalize is usually combined with other things, such as an SVM or a random forest or whatever, into a pipeline so that you can run all these different things as a single model. It doesn't really make much sense to have *only* a Normalize.

Comment: I trained with Keras TF. I use SKLearn only for normalization and scaling. In this case according to you these should be a part of my keras model using tf components and not SKLearn. Correct?

Comment: Yes indeed. I don't think the coremltools sklearn converter was intended for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the input dimensions like this:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(normalized, input_features={'input': [0, 1, 2]})
```

Where `input` here is the input feature name (which is `input` by default) and the list (`[0, 1, 2]`) is the input feature IDs (for simplicity, you can just do `range(num_features)`, or just list the index values explicitly like I did).